# Scrapy Mongodb - crawl multiple spider and save in different multiple mongo collection

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data and saved in a mongo database.There are two file (whole.py and admissionReq.py) which does the scraping, but both scraped data are being saved in one collection 'courses'

Here are my file:

```
whole.py: https://pastebin.com/ZpSER6wr

admissionReq: https://pastebin.com/5CQ7qRBM

settings.py: https://pastebin.com/dnPNqveq

pipelines: https://pastebin.com/YRfWiFhF

items: https://pastebin.com/1FGprEJj
```

i want

1. whole.py: scraped data to save in a mongo collection called 'courses'
2. admissionReq.py: scraped data to save in a mongo collection called 'admissionReq'

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: FYI it’s scrape, scraper, scraped, scraping not scrap/scrapper/scrapped/scrapping. Scrap etc. are about throwing things away like rubbish, and you’re not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are passing the collection name in your pipeline from `scrapy.conf.settings`
This remains the same for all spiders which means that all items processed through the pipeline will be inserted in the same collection named in `scrapy.conf.settings`

Instead what you can do is specify the name of the collection for a particular spider in the spider's settings like so:

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'foo'

custom_settings = {
    'COLLECTION_NAME' : 'foo'
}
```

Then retrieve that setting in your mongo pipeline like so:

```
import pymongo

class MongoPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(
        mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
        mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE')
    )

def open_spider(self,spider):
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.client.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.db[spider.settings.get('COLLECTION_NAME')].insert_one(dict(item))
    return item
```

Notice in `process_item(self, item, spider`, I retrieve the `COLLECTION_NAME` parameter from `spider.settings.get('COLLECTION_NAME')`